# Can't insert element into vector of a class which contains a reference

Tags: c++, vector, stl

I have a class, which has a reference to another struct.

```
struct DNA { ... };
class Cohort {
    private:
        DNA& genetics;
        ...
    public:
        Cohort(DNA& g) : genetics(g) {}
        ...
};
```

I then have a vector of `Cohort`s.

```
std::vector<Cohort> cohorts;
```

I must then insert Cohorts at the beginning of the vector.

```
cohorts.insert(cohorts.begin(), Cohort(eggs, genetics));
```

I get an error.

```
error: object of type 'Thor_Lucas_Development::Cohort' cannot be assigned because its copy assignment
      operator is implicitly deleted
```

I'm assuming when items are inserted into the vector, it's copied in. Because I have a reference in my `Cohort`s class, it's copy assignment operator is implicitly deleted.

So... what's going on? I just can't use vectors when dealing with the `Cohort` class? Or *must* I `new` up the `Cohort` and have pointers to it in the vector?

Kind of annoying.

Comment: Copy assignment operator will be implicitly deleted for the class if you have non-static reference member variable. What you can do is to write the copy assignment operator manually.

Comment: Why do you need a *non-static* reference member?

Comment: BTW, what is `eggs`?

Comment: @codekaizer My bad, I was using incomplete code here so I don't have to copy and paste the whole code. It's just the number of eggs laid by the queen bee in that period which is calculated using differential equations.

Comment: @codekaizer I don't want to continuously make copies of the genetics struct because it would take a lot of memory considering I'll have a whole bunch of cohorts.

Answer (score 1):

You can construct the object in place:

```
cohorts.emplace(cohorts.begin(), eggs, genetics);
```

But reference members are rarely a good idea – use a pointer instead.
And if you insert at the beginning a lot, you probably want `std::deque` rather than `std::vector`.

Comment: Thanks! I think I tried that earlier and it didn't work for whatever reason, but I'll try it again and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

As the error message says, you cannot rebind a reference in a living object, that is why assignment is deleted by default.

Besides storing pointers in the vector, you can somehow rewrite your class:

I. Use pointers instead of references. They are quite value-like in this usecase:

```
#include <vector>

struct Nyan {
    int *x;
};

int main() {
    int x;
    std::vector<Nyan> v{{&x}, {&x}, {&x}};
    v.insert(v.begin(), Nyan{&x});
}
```

(As a replacement for reference, plain pointer is quite OK, but you can use any of the wrappers defined in `<memory>` should you ever need it.)

You can even add some protection to disallow null pointers:

```
struct Nyan {
    Nyan(int &x): x(&x) {}
private:
    int *x;
};
```

II. `std::reference_wrapper` was introduced in as early as C++11 to accommodate for unrebindability, to allow to store references in containers:

```
#include <vector>
#include <functional>

struct Nyan {
    std::reference_wrapper<int> x;
};

int main() {
    int x;
    std::vector<Nyan> v{{x}, {x}, {x}};
    v.insert(v.begin(), Nyan{x});
}
```